# Pandas: Compare every two rows and output result to a new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID':['i1', 'i2', 'i3'],
                   'A': [2, 3, 1],
                   'B': [1, 1, 2],
                   'C': [2, 1, 0],
                   'D': [3, 1, 2]})

df1.set_index('ID')

df1.head()


    A   B   C   D  
ID          
i1  2   1   2   3   
i2  3   1   1   1   
i3  1   2   0   2


df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID':['i1-i2', 'i1-i3', 'i2-i3'],
                   'A': [2, 1, 1],
                   'B': [1, 1, 1],
                   'C': [1, 0, 0],
                   'D': [1, 1, 1]})

df2.set_index('ID')
df2

        A   B   C   D
ID              
i1-i2   2   1   1   1
i1-i3   1   1   0   1
i2-i3   1   1   0   1
```

Given a data frame as df1, I want to compare every two different rows, and get the smaller value at each column, and output the result to a new data frame like df2. 
For example, to compare `i1` row and `i2` row, get new row `i1-i2` as `2, 1, 1, 1`
Please advise what is the best way of pandas to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
from itertools import combinations

v = df1.values

r = pd.DataFrame([np.minimum(v[t[0]], v[t[1]])
                  for t in combinations(np.arange(len(df1)), 2)],
                 columns=df1.columns,
                 index=list(combinations(df1.index, 2)))
```

Result:

```
In [72]: r
Out[72]:
          A  B  C  D
(i1, i2)  2  1  1  1
(i1, i3)  1  1  0  2
(i2, i3)  1  1  0  1
```

Comment: it is beautiful way to make the combinations. But the new dataframe has the ID combinations lost. Could you suggest a way to keep that?